# Error in Singleton pattern implementation

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I see errors like

src/singleton.cxx:16:error:  invalid use of member 'Singleton::instance' in static member function
src/singleton.cxx:28:error:  from this location
src/singleton.cxx:16:error:  invalid use of member 'Singleton::instance' in static member function
src/singleton.cxx:29:error:  from this location
src/singleton.cxx:16:error:  invalid use of member 'Singleton::instance' in static member function
src/singleton.cxx:31:error:  from this location
src/singleton.cxx: In function 'int main()':

Now after making changes I get the following errors

singleton-rhel6.3.o: In function `Singleton::get_instance()':
src/singleton.cxx:27: undefined reference to`Singleton::instance'

```
#include <cstddef>

class Singleton {

private:
  Singleton();
  static Singleton * instance;
  int m_num;
  int incr_call();

public :
  static Singleton * get_instance();

};

Singleton * Singleton::get_instance() {
  if(instance == NULL)
    instance = new Singleton();
  return instance;
}

Singleton::Singleton():
  m_num(0)
{
}

int Singleton::incr_call() {
  return m_num++;
}

int main() {
  Singleton * s = Singleton::get_instance();
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: not the problem but `Singleton * instance;` should not be public

Comment: instance should be static. Although you may want to consider Bjarne Stroustrup's implementation of this instead.

Comment: Read up on static member functions.

Comment: This may be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1008289/3807729

Comment: @Galik the link you show me has the static instance declared in the public section too

Comment: After the edit that fixed the original problem, I assume the errors are different. With that said you are not supposed to modify the code after it has been answered since it invalidates the answer. And makes the question confusing to future readers.

Comment: so whats the protocol, should i post an answer, with edited code ? i have provided the new errors ...btw

Comment: Normally you ask a different question (since it is a different problem) and leave the original question alone.

Comment: For this case I my advice is to use the code @Jarod42 just posted. That is what I meant on my first comment (about the alternate implementation)!

Answer (score 1):

`instance` should be `static` since you want to be able to call it in `get_instance`. Also, `instance` should be `private`:

```
class Singleton {

public :
  static Singleton * get_instance();


private:
  Singleton();
  static Singleton * instance;
  int m_num;
  int incr_call();

};
Singleton* Singleton::instance;
```

You should change your constructor too, to not initialize `instance`:

```
Singleton::Singleton():
  m_num(0)
{ }
```

Because `instance` is `static` default initialization is done and it will be `NULL / nullptr`.

Comment: i made these changes, and it still complains when instance is compared to NULL

Comment: You probably forgot `Singleton* Singleton::instance;`

Answer (score 1):

If you have to use singleton, use Meyers' one:

```
class Singleton {
private:
    Singleton() = default;
    Singleton(const Singleton&) = delete;
    Singleton& operator=(const Singleton&) = delete;

public :
    static Singleton& get_instance()
    {
        static Singleton instance;
        return instance;
    }

// Extra stuff
};
```

Comment: i dont understand this. I read the concept of singleton, saw some examples and trying to implement it. what does meyers do thats fixing the problem im having ?

Comment: This code is simpler than yours and avoids the static initialization order  fiasco https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order